# How can i access the ['question'] inside a loop?

Tags: twig

```
Array ( [status] => 1 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [61d2f1fef27db255838d2c59] => Array ( 
            [name] => General 
            [questions] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 61d54149c98b65a672acf79b 
                    [question] => What will happen to posts that I made on my classic Page? 
                    [answer] => All of your previous posts will be preserved on your Page, and insights will still be available for them. 
                    ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 61d2eb5db97dcc3c488f0ef9 
                    [question] => How can I add my Google Analytics id in for the mobile website ? 
                    [answer] => Before starting, Please keep your Google Analytics id ready with you. Go to the Settings > Manage Design > Data Settings and enter your id in the analytics id field & save. Please refer to the video for step by step help. 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        [61d53eb4c98b65a672acf798] => Array ( 
            [name] => Other 
            [questions] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 61d54131c98b65a672acf79a 
                    [question] => How can I open my new Page? 
                    [answer] => To open your new Page on desktop: From your home page, click on your profile picture in the top right. Select Switch Profile and select the new Page. 
                    ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 61d53fc9c98b65a672acf799 
                    [question] => What is your return policy? 
                    [answer] => We allow returns of all items within 30 days of your order date. Just send us an email with your order number and we will send you a return label. 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

I am new to twig and i have got this data and want to access the every [question] and [answer] data. Please someone help me in order to extract question and answer using twig looping statements.

```
{% for data in api_response %}
    {% for keys in data %}
        {{ keys }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried it doing this way but i am not getting any output

Comment: I mean, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Not quite sure why this would be a problem if you read through the basic documentation

Comment: I am getting the result but i am doing it hard coded. As i am new to the twig i am facing some errors using loop. please help me with the looping code

Comment: At least post some of the efforts you've tried.

Comment: Please review the code

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you are only using one loop, but as we can see, the questions are stored in another array. Meaning you'll have to loop that array as well

```
{% for row in result.data %}
    <h2>{{ row.name }}</h2>
    {% for data in row.questions %}
        <p>{{ data.question }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/5c2jfp)

---

Edit from comment:

```
{% for row in result.data %}
    {% if row.name|lower = 'general' %}
        <h2>{{ row.name }}</h2>
        {% for data in row.questions %}
            <p>{{ data.question }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If i just want to access the questions from general?

Comment: Then it's actually better to restructure the data before sending the data to the view, but you could add an if-statement. Keep in mind that you can't break out of loops in twig